# ios9 <input type="file" accepts="image/*"> shows only blank screen when taking camera picture

Tags: html, iphone, image, file-upload, ios9

I want visitors with IOS9 Phones to be able to upload pictures on my webserver over a webpage. On IOS8 and previous versions, this could be simply achieved by using the input element: `<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*">`

Since IOS9, the IPhone's camera app will only display a blank screen when choosing to upload a picture with the camera.

I wrote a small testscript to demonstrate the Problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="new-submission-file" accept="image/*">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="new-submission-file2" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg">
 </body>
</html>
```

You can find it here: http://drl.lu-re.de/os9test/

Is there any workaround or do we have to wait for a bugfix from apple?

Comment: image/x-png? png's been a standardized for a long time now. it's officially image/png. x-png was for when it was new and hadn't been given an official mime type yet.

Answer (score 1):

this is a permission issue, go to settings -> privacy -> camera and enable the browser access

Comment: Thanks, you saved my time. A black screen and without any message. I couldn't imagine that type of "message" about permission being denied...